# Fetch KEY VALUE pair from a SQL Server column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2008

I have a Column called `JsonData` in SQL Server table which has the data as key/value pairs, 
like this:

> {"Id":42662,"VersionNumber":0,"IsCustom":false,"SaleType":0,"RedBookSpotId":232164,"RegistrationNumber":"AUTOTEST","Price":29500.00,"RegistrationExpiryYear":2013,"RegistrationExpiryMonth":9,"HasRWCertificate":false,"Odometer":43842,"ExteriorColour":"Blue","InteriorColour":"Black","SummaryDescription":"This
>   is an automation test ad - Short Comments","DetailedDescription":"This
>   is an automation test ad - Detailed
>   Comments","StandardFeatures":[],"OptionalFeatures":[],"AfterMarketFeatures":[]}

I want to write a T-SQL query to only fetch the value for `Odometer` key

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server 2008 has no support for JSON data types](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/673824/add-native-support-for-json-to-sql-server-a-la-xml-as-in-for-json-or-from-openjson). you can add your name to the list of people requesting it.

If you know the column ordering, I guess you could write a complex query using the substring function, but that violates quite a bit of the key/value pair usefulness of JSON.

There has also been some [effort by third parties to add JSON functionality to SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/?__utma=190281897.540859658.1372908309.1372908309.1372992051.2&__utmb=190281897.2.10.1372992051&__utmc=190281897&__utmx=-&__utmz=190281897.1372992051.2.2.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=263588428).

If you need to query on only one or two columns, I would recommend inserting and updating them directly into columns in the table rather than querying through the stored JSON. It's a slight duplication of data, but consider how easy the answer to your question becomes in that scenario.

FYI [PostgreSQL 9.3 has support for JSON data types](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-json-parsing-functions/) that's getting better every release.

Comment: thanks for replying, I managed it by adding the data as a column instead of a json string